# visual c profiler not giving meaningful results

Tags: c, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, profiler

I am using Visual Studio 2010  Premium version

When I run the profiler, it runs fine, but then it just produces results telling me that my app [appName.exe] (brackets are theirs) is using 99.99% of the time spent.

I googled trying to find anyone reporting similar issues, but to no avail. I am using Windows 7, compiling using x64 for my multi-threaded app. However, even when I turn off all the multithread pragma directives, same results.

The last time I used the profiler on my app it worked as one would expect, telling which functions were the most expensive.

Btw, I am using c, not c++, if that makes any difference.

Any ideas?

Comment: I work on the profiler and if you are seeing `[appName.exe]` in the calltree or functions view, it would indicate that you do not have your symbols currently set.  Are you profiling a loaded Solution or targeting a specific EXE?  What view are you seeing this in?

Comment: BTW, C or C++ does not matter.  The profiler is language agnostic.  It only cares if it is Native or .NET.

Comment: Thank you.  Apparently somehow I got it set to analyze the release (vs debug) version.  I'm am an oldie (not a newbie), returning to programming after 20 years, and all these tools are pretty amazing...how pleasant to not have to use printf to debug/profile.  So just to be clear, the profiler is meant to profile the debug version, which has all the symbols.  Thanks again.

Comment: No actually the profiler can profile any application.  You will only get usable data if symbols are present though.  It could be the case that your Project is configured to not create symbols for a 'Release' build, but I do not think that is the default.  If you have any specific issues with profiling you can follow the Profiler link in my Stackoverflow profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you. Apparently somehow I got it set to analyze the release (vs debug) version.